# How to solve ReactJs (typescript) mapping issue, map() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to update an item from a list of items using map in ReactJs (with TypeScript). But cannot find the issue.

```
const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([])
```

...

```
setOrderList( orderList.map( order:any => {
    if( order.id == orderId)
        return {...order, review_id:1} 
    return order
}))
```

the following typescript hint is showing:

```
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never put type annotations on inline callback parameters. It's an awful coding pattern that hides bugs and is wholely pointless

Answer (score 2):

*First*, pass an array of the correct type to `useState` so that it returns a properly typed state and setter function

```
const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState([] as Order[]);
```

This is necessary because the inferred type of the expression `[]` since there is no context for TypeScript to infer from in this case. In this case I've used a type assertion but there are other ways as well (`useState<Order[]>([])` for example).

*Second*, never put type annotations on inline callback parameters. It's an awful coding pattern that hides bugs and is wholely pointless because type inference ensures safety and correct type propagation.

```
setOrderList(orderList.map(order => {
  if (order.id === orderId)
    return {...order, review_id: 1};
  return order;
}));
```

**Note:**

As noted by others, if you have a unary arrow function that needs a type annotation on its parameter, then you must surround the parameter list with parentheses. For example

```
const processOrder = (o: Order) => {...};
```

In the above, we only annotated `o` with a type because there was no inference context for the language to infer its type.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `const [orderList, setOrderList] = useState<any[]>([])`.

By the way, I don't know if you noticed, but the idea of using typescript is to avoid using `any`.

Answer (score 0):

just use a parentheses **()** in the *map* callback

```
orderList.map((order:any) => {
  if(order.id === orderId) {
     return {...order, review_id:1} 
  }
  return order
});
```